# Grails, hasMany relation for non domain class?

Tags: hibernate, grails, persistence, grails-orm

I have some doubts with grails and the persistence. For example, let's suppose I have two classes:

One is a domain class (*Person*)

```
class Person{
    String name
    int age
    House house
}
```

and the other (*House*) is in **src/groovy**.

```
class House{
    String address
}
```

I know that using a custom hibernate types for House I can persist without problems. But I don't know how to do it if I have in the Person class a collection of houses, something like:

```
Set<House> houses = [] //in Person class
```

If I change House to be a domain class I have no problems because I can use the ***hasMany relationship***, but House being in src/groovy I have no idea =/

It's this possible? Maybe I'm mixing some concepts. Hope someone can help me, any suggestions, idea are much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just make `House` a domain class?

Comment: One reason to not make it a domain class is that Grails adds over 100 methods to domain classes, and they're real methods in the bytecode, not metaclass methods. But something similar that would leave House untouched would be to create an empty subclass of House under grails-app/domain and use that instead

Comment: Mmmm I don't want that the object maintain the "identity". Let's say that for me it's just a collection of houses, I mean that I don’t care about any particular House object as an entity.... but thinking a bit not sure if I should see it as an value object :/